# PHAsset copy video completion

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager, phasset, file-manager

I wish to copy video file from Photo Library to my app's Documents directory and wish to be notified about completion. Here is what I do:

```
    let videoAsset = fetchResult.object(at: indexPath.item)
    print(videoAsset.description)

    let options = PHVideoRequestOptions()
    options.version = .original

    PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: videoAsset, options: options) { [weak self] (avAsset, audioMix, info) in

        if let avurlAsset = avAsset as? AVURLAsset {
            let url = avurlAsset.url
            let toUrl = //some Url
            let fileManager = FileManager.default

            do {
              try fileManager.copyItem(at: url, to: toUrl)
            } catch {
               NSLog("Unable to copy file from \(url) to \(toUrl)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Only problem with this approach is I have no way to be notified of completion of copyItem. What is the alternative to copyItem method (or altogether a different approach to above) that is atleast blocking till copy finishes? Is it possible to use FileHandle & read consecutive bytes and write to another file? Will that be synchronous enough?

EDIT: As pointed by Alex, copyItem is actually synchronous routine. On closer inspection, I see I sometimes get errors on copying. Not sure why the permission errors show up when it is app's Documents folder where I copy.

```
  2018-08-27 20:30:07.485841+0530 MyProject[3577:1288452] Copying file...
2018-08-27 20:30:07.487880+0530 MyProject[3577:1288452] stat on /var/mobile/Media/DCIM/107APPLE/IMG_7915.MP4: Operation not permitted
2018-08-27 20:30:07.512994+0530
 MyProject[3577:1288452] Unable to copy file from    file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/107APPLE/IMG_7915.MP4 to    file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CC13FD5A-E4CF-42A1-931F-2F1FFE799C15/Documents/IMG-0027.mov, Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "“IMG_7915.MP4” couldn’t be copied because you don’t have permission to access “Documents”." UserInfo=   
{NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/107APPLE/IMG_7915.MP4,    NSUserStringVariant=(
   Copy
  ),   

  NSDestinationFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CC13FD5A-E4CF-42A1-931F-2F1FFE799C15/Documents/IMG-0027.mov, NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/107APPLE/IMG_7915.MP4, NSUnderlyingError=0x111c441c0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Copyitem: Copies the item at the specified path to a new location synchronously.

Returns true if the item was copied successfully or the file manager’s delegate stopped the operation deliberately. Returns false if an error occurred.

This is a sync method so after it executed after catch without error then it means successful copied.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1407903-copyitem

Comment: It appears there were actually copy errors. I have updated the question with an Edit.

Comment: Try to add permission into plist according to your log. Because it says : because you don’t have permission to access “Documents”.